# client denied by server configuration after reinstalling KDE Desktop and SDDM

Tags: ubuntu, kde, apache-virtualhost

Systeminfos:

```
Ubuntu 22.04
KDE-Plasma-Version: 5.24.6
KDE-Frameworks-Version: 5.92.0
Qt-Version: 5.15.3
Kernel-Version: 5.15.0-10048-tuxedo (64-bit)
Apache 2.4.52
```

During a system cleanup, I seem to have uninstalled something that caused the following error to occur after a reboot.

```
The current theme cannot be loaded due to the errors below, please select another theme.
file///usr/share/sddm/breeze/main.qml: No such file or directory
```

In the terminal I then executed the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm-theme-breeze
sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
sudo apt install --reinstall kde-plasma-desktop
sudo apt install --reinstall kde-standard

sudo systemctl unmask packagekit.service
sudo systemctl start packagekit.service
sudo systemctl unmask mysql.service
sudo systemctl unmask apache2.service

but mysql did not worked so i had to reinstall it
sudo apt-get --purge mysql*
sudo apt install --reinstall mysql
sudo apt install mysql-server

sudo chmod o+x $HOME
```

After that the login and the KDE desktop worked again.

However, I now have a problem with the local web server.
When I call a local page I get a 500 error in the browser.

vhost

```
<VirtualHost local.mydomain.de:443>
        ServerName local.mydomain.de:443
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/user/_projects/mydomain/webroot/
        <Directory /home/user/_projects/mydomain/webroot/>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /home/user/local.mydomain.de+3.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/user/local.mydomain.de+3-key.pem

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-mydomain.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-mydomain.log combined
        ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

Checking the apache2 error.log gives me this message

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 8214] [client 127.0.0.1:41014] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/user/_projects/
```

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.conf: Permission denied
Action '-M' failed
```

Now I can't figure out how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this solution was the only one that helped to get apache working

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-data apache2-utils
sudo apt-get install apache2
```